# MS-Access 2010 DELETE Query LEFT JOIN

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

There's a lot of these issues floating around the net with many solutions, but I'm really struggling with this one.

I have a table [BaseHrs] which looks a little like this -

```
p_ID  b_Person  WeekNos  HrsRequired
1     A         2016-39  10
1     A         2016-40  10
1     A         2016-41  10
1     A         2016-42  10
1     B         2016-39  11
1     B         2016-40  11
1     B         2016-41  12
1     B         2016-42  09
```

The table continues with different p_ID, people & week numbers.  There is no Primary Key and no indexing.  This table also has no relationship with any other table.

It is populated from a Query connected to another table as well as a form for the [HrsRequired] field.

Scenario -
Project 1 (p_ID=1) has now been brought forward by two weeks and BaseHrs table no longer needs row for [WeekNos] 2016-41 & 2016-42.

I initially use a query to show which weeks the project is now running on (qry_SelectNewDates).

I have started my delete query by first creating a Select query which looks like this -

```
SELECT BaseHrs.*
FROM BaseHrs 
LEFT JOIN qry_SelectNewDates 
    ON BaseHrs.WeekNos = qry_SelectNewDates.WeekNos
    WHERE (((BaseHrs.p_ID)=[Forms]![frm_Projects]![p_ID]) 
        AND ((BaseHrs.WeekNos) Not In ([qry_SelectNewDates].[WeekNos])));
```

This works as intended.

Converting that into a delete query produces an error though.  Delete Query -

```
DELETE BaseHrs.*, BaseHrs.p_ID, BaseHrs.WeekNos
FROM BaseHrs 
LEFT JOIN qry_SelectNewDates 
ON BaseHrs.WeekNos = qry_SelectNewDates.WeekNos
WHERE (((BaseHrs.p_ID)=[Forms]![frm_Projects]![p_ID]) 
AND ((BaseHrs.WeekNos) Not In ([qry_SelectNewDates].[WeekNos])));
```

Error message -

> Could not delete from specified tables.

I realise that there is often an issue when trying to delete records in this way.  I've tried using it with just 'DELETE.*' in the first line without luck.

I have also made an attempt at a nested Query, but I just can't figure out how to construct it.  Any guidance?

**********EDIT**********

With advice from @SunKnight0 I have added a primary key to my BaseHrs table and got this query -

```
DELETE *
FROM BaseHrs
WHERE b_pKey IN
   (SELECT BaseHrs.b_pKey
    FROM BaseHrs 
    LEFT JOIN qry_SelectNewDates 
        ON (BaseHrs.WeekNos = qry_SelectNewDates.WeekNos)
    WHERE (((BaseHrs.p_ID)=[Forms]![frm_Projects]![p_ID]) 
        AND ((BaseHrs.WeekNos) Not In ([qry_SelectNewDates].[WeekNos]))));
```

This query appears to work but takes a huge amount of time to run.  Is that as good as it gets?

Comment: It keeps amazing me that people are designing database table without a primary key. Here is how easy it would be to do what you want if you had one: `DELETE FROM table WHERE KeyID IN (SELECT KeyID  FROM table [rest of query that gets the KeyIDs you want to delete with all the JOINS you need])`

Comment: Haven't been at this long.  I made a table that will be holding records only as long as a person is attached to each project.  Records will be added and removed quite often.  I thought about an autonumber but on creation, didn't think it would be necessary.  In hindsight I possibly made the wrong choice.  I'll stick one in and see how it goes.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help. It should be straightforward once you have a primary key because you already seem to have the subquery you need. Generally, unless you have a very specific reason not to want a primary key in your tables, you should always include one. It tends to make life a lot easier and usually boosts performance.

Comment: @SunKnight0 If you're up for it I may need just a little more help.  I've added some more to the end of my question.  The query works but is super slow.  Is there a better way?

Comment: One sure way to make it faster is to convert `qry_SelectNewDates` into a table. Beyond that I would need to see a lot more of your setup to provide useful feedback.

Comment: From quick glance, repeating `FROM BaseHrs` twice appears unnecessary but @SunKnight0 has led you down this path so perhaps he should be prepared to debug this...?

Comment: @SunKnight0: "It keeps amazing me that people are designing database table without a primary key" - I don't think you've understood the concept of primary key. In context you seem to rather mean 'surrogate key' probably using auto-number.

Comment: @onedaywhen Is there a better way?  Your answer returned a syntax error, but I would have carried on working on both techniques.